# Bootstrap2 20px padding on both-sides of screen at 767px and below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, padding

good evening, I am using Joomla built in Bootstrap2. I am making website in full width view, the problem is below 768px 20px padding add on both sides of the screen. I have added following but its not working:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

    .container-fluid {
     padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Comment: Just make it compulsory by adding (!important) like this:

padding:0px !important

Comment: !important is not working i added it. It was happening on 979px too i added same padding: 0; it worked but for some reason its not working for 767px and below.

Comment: Can you just show the code using any online editor? @AwaisRaza

Comment: Try appending ancestor element like this  body .container-fluid{ attribute }

Comment: Okay got it! Just change .container-fluid to body tag and it will work! @AwaisRaza

Comment: I have posted as answer! It was pleasure to help you out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the rule defined in the responsive-bootstrap.min.css. Code in that file is :

```
@media (max-width:767px) {    
    body{
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
    }
}
```

So to make it zero you have to override that rule so replace your code with this:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {    
    body{
     padding: 0px;
    }
}
```